# How to get userInformation on the default page after login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm actually working on my first webpage with asp.
In my project I got different pages. 
One for the Login:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="User_Login_CS.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Menustyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--Menu -->
    <div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="Index.aspx">
                        <img src="logo.png"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="DetailView.aspx?call=104"><span class="auto-style1"><strong>Enter Data</strong></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Overview.aspx"><span class="auto-style1"><strong>Overview</strong></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="ManagementReport.aspx"><span class="auto-style1"><strong>Management Report</strong></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style2">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style5"></td>
                <td class="auto-style6"></td>
                <td class="auto-style7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser">
                    </asp:Login>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Behind the Login:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace User_Login_CS
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=true";

        protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userId = 0;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    con.Close();
                }
                switch (userId)
                {
                    case -1:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                        break;
                    default:
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the login I redircet the user to my default-page. My Question now: What I have to to that the user authentication is alive for all my pages and how can I Access the user data on my default page?

Thanks for your Help and Time!
Greets

Comment: If user login successfully then return user record and store user data into session or cookie. After use this data to any where.

Comment: please google *how to use session in asp.net**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already told and the other solutions did you have to use Sessions. There are several good  tutorials. Just search for them with google. For example this one:http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/. 
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Load user data in a class and store it in the session

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the whole user info into session, only need to store username or userid into cookie:

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.................

    //If user logins successfully then authenticate username into cookie
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
}
```

Then from anywhere in the project, you can always get username of current logging user and load the related user info from database like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var currentUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    //Load other user info here...
    var userInfo = LoadUserInfoByUsername(currentUserName);

    //Do something with user info....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet are  both of type string

Try this :

```
switch (userId)
                {
                    case -1:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                        break;
                    default:
Session["UserName"]=Login1.UserName; Session["RememberMeSet"]=Login1.RememberMeSet;

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                        break;
                }
```